# Rapid Population Growth in Early Game

Tags: cities-skylines

In Cities: Skylines I find that sometimes I miss something when initially setting up a new city, be it connecting power, finalizing a water / sewage supply or whatever.   This typically results in having to restart the game and watching it load again.

Is there anyway to speed up population growth, other than cheats or mods, that would allow a city to not loose money so that the loans feature can be enabled sooner?  Or is there some other way of bringing in money rapidly to pay for essential items before people abandon their homes?

Answer (score 2):

You need constant growth without growth spurts. Your problem is likely related to growing to rapidly and, thereby, your population demanding services that become available with milestones without having the necessary funds to buy and support them.

Grow your city slowly, adding only a few residential zones at a time and focus first on breaking even and then generating a small profit. As long as your cims are employed they will remain in the city and generate some revenue.

At that point speed up your game time and accumulate some funds before expanding past the next milestone. Rinse and repeat until you have unlocked all basic categories relating to garbage disposal, crime, health, and education (fires don't seem to matter much).

Comment: Valid points but I'm on about the early game, the start. As mentioned every so often I might forget something small, be it a water pipe connection or electricity line. When that happens it takes a while to notice, and ends with a lengthy restart.  Essentially I'm trying to see if there is a more convenient way to fix my initial blunders.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, how can a simple pipeline be a  problem early in the game? You should have enough funds to cover it.

Comment: As I've said its for times when I overstretch and miss something, or misjudge how far to put power lines (these are just examples). The early part of the setup has the city loosing money, so without funds the final pieces are not available to buy.

Comment: Ah I see your problem. The solution is easy and I stated it; constant growth. This requires you grow in small increments. Don't plan big from the start. Go easy and try making a profit before expanding.

Comment: Not really.  See I already know that, what I want to know is if there is a way of fixing mistakes, rather than starting over and doing it right the next time.  This is about recovery - not how to start.

Comment: Well I presume you know that you are able to demolish what you constructed before. Considering that your issue is turning a profit before you run out of money to get you infrastructure going, your issue is that you are planning to big and spend to much money. Apart from saving and loading, only steady, planned growth will fix your issue.